# Android ProgressDialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I can't make ProgressDialog run in AsyncTask :

```
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
ProgressDialog pd;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Message");
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.setMax(100);
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

       @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                .......

                 public void write(byte[] bts, int st, int end) throws IOException {
                            totalSent += end;
                            progress = (int) ((totalSent / (float) contentLength) * 100);
                            publishProgress("Loaded "+progress+"%");
                            out.write(bts, st, end);
                        } 

                 .......

                }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
            pd.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                  super.onPostExecute(result);
          if (pd != null)
          {
             pd.dismiss();
          } 
              }
```

Progress dialog works, but no progress on it. However in logs I see, that progress counts properly.
So, no problems in progress count.

For the code above I get an error, saying "The method publishProgress(Void...) in the type AsyncTask String,Void,Void is not applicable for the arguments (String)".

It doesn't work no matter what I do. I suppose, that I miss something. Please help )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a `parseInt` on a String containing `"Loaded "+progress+"%"`. It can't work. Try this :

```
publishProgress(""+progress);

// [...]

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
{
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Loaded " + progress[0] + "%");
    pd.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
```

Comment: This plus  -   private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>   , as DevrimTuncer suggested below, made it work. Tks to all )

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressUpdate`'s paramater is defied at AsyncTask's second generic type.

Change this:

```
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
```

to this:

```
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
```

and update this method:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
{
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Loaded " + progress[0] + "%");
    pd.setProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

You can read more about [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. But combining with ToYonos reply above it works. Unfortunately I can't accept two replies ) Tks )